# Simulation of t copula in Python

Tags: python, scipy, simulation

I am trying to simulate a t-copula using Python, but my code yields strange results (is not well-behaving):

I followed the approach suggested by [Demarta & McNeil](http://www.ressources-actuarielles.net/EXT/ISFA/1226.nsf/0/303eb11b4d617b79c1257b0800744575/$FILE/t%20copula%20demarta%20mcneil.pdf) (2004) in "The t Copula and Related Copulas", which states:

[image: t copula simulation]

By intuition, I know that the higher the degrees of freedom parameter, the more the t copula should resemble the Gaussian one (and hence the lower the tail dependency). However, given that I sample from `scipy.stats.invgamma.rvs` or alternatively from `scipy.stats.chi2.rvs`, yields higher values for my parameter `s` the higher my parameter `df`. This does not made any sense, as I found multiple papers stating that for `df`--> `inf`, t-copula --> Gaussian copula.

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong? (I'm a beginner in Python fyi).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import invgamma, chi2, t

#Define number of sampling points
n_samples = 1000
df = 10

calib_correl_matrix = np.array([[1,0.8,],[0.8,1]]) #I just took a bivariate correlation matrix here
mu = np.zeros(len(calib_correl_matrix))
s = chi2.rvs(df)
#s = invgamma.pdf(df/2,df/2) 
Z = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, calib_correl_matrix,n_samples)
X = np.sqrt(df/s)*Z #chi-square method
#X = np.sqrt(s)*Z #inverse gamma method

U = t.cdf(X,df)
```

My outcomes behave exactly oppisite to what I am (should be) expecting: 
Higher `df` create much higher tail-dependency, here also visually:

```
 U_pd = pd.DataFrame(U)
 fig = plt.gcf()
 fig.set_size_inches(14.5, 10.5)
 pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(U_pd, figsize=(14,10), diagonal = 'kde')
 plt.show()
```

`df=4`:
[image: scatter_plot]

`df=100`:
[image]

It gets especially worse when using the `invgamma.rvs` directly, even though they should yield the same. For dfs>=30 I often receive a ValueError ("ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs")

Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: can you provide the code that you can replicate? you are missing the imports, hard to guess what is `chi2.rvs`?

Comment: Sure: 
    `import numpy as np`,
    `import pandas as pd`,
    `from scipy.stats import invgamma`,
    `from scipy.stats import chi2`,
    `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` thank you very much for your help!

Comment: and `U = sc.stats.t.cdf(X,df)` is...?

Comment: `sc.stats` = `scipy.stats`

Comment: I have a vague guess `t_m `and `t_v` are not accounted in code as different. Should they?

Comment: Basically, `X`is the simulated `t_m` and then to generate `U` the matrix X is plugged into `t_v` in my code. You suggest to insert `X_i` elementwise into respective `t_v`?

Comment: I'm missing what `m` is in `t_m` in point 1.

Comment: `t_m` is a multivariate Student t distribution, while `t_v` is the univariate marginal cdf. The dimension of `t_m` is given by the correlation matrix (here 2x2 -> two-dimensional),

Comment: For U are you sure it it cdf, not pdf?

Comment: Yes, because the copula works in the [0,1]^d space and out of it you generate a vector, which later on reflects the y-axes of the underlying univariate CDFs for each series. A pdf would not depict in [0,1] but rather a space much smaller than 1

Comment: Maybe cross-post to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copula? Your question begs for proper answer!

Comment: Have done that! Thanks! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359297/simulation-of-t-copula-in-python

Comment: If that does not work for some reason, I can repost later with a bounty - which possibly can attract more answeres.

Comment: That would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, so far nobody reacted to it unfortunately - could you repost it? :)

Comment: I used a bounty to attract readers, but to no success. The points from a bounty were gone, even without an answer! Can you drop me a line at my email or twitter?

Comment: @rhonsprudel: are you still interested in tracking this down?  Because some tests I've done suggest there's nothing really wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

There is one obvious problem in your code. Namely, this:

```
s = chi2.rvs(df)
```

Has to be changed to something like that:

```
s = chi2.rvs(df, size=n_samples)[:, np.newaxis]
```

Otherwise the variable `s` is just a single constant and your `X` ends up being a sample from the multivariate normal (scaled by `np.sqrt(df/s)`), rather than the t-distrubution that you need.

You most probably obtained your "tail-heavy" charts simply because you were unlucky and your sampled value of `s` ended up being too small. This has nothing to do with `df`, though, yet it seems that it is easier to hit the "unlucky" values when `df` is smaller.